# Lua 4.01 loops and variables optimization

Tags: loops, optimization, lua

In Lua 4.01, will the second example loop be more efficient than the first? (Sorry, I don't know the correct terminology to describe the problem.)

```
for k = 1, getn(myTable) do
    ...
end

local numTable = getn(myTable)
for k = 1, numTable do
    ...
end
```

Also what about the third versus the fourth examples:

```
for k = 1, 4 do
    bigTable[3][k]
    ...
end

local tempTable = bigTable[3]
for k = 1, 4 do
    tempTable[k]
    ...
end
```

I know in some scripting languages this is the case. Thanks.

[edit]

I just came up with some test code to check examples #1 vs #2.

```
function Return_a_Number()
    print("############# I am looping.")
    return 5
end

for i = 1, Return_a_Number() do
    -- do nothing
end
```

This shows that the getn() function in example #1 is only executed once total instead of once per looping. This is a good thing.

Comment: 1 vs 2: 1, though it doesn't change that much. 3 vs 4: definitely 4, only one table access per loop plus `tempTable` is local which means accessing it is faster.

Comment: The reason I ask about #1 vs #2 is that in some languages (JavaScript) the getn bit would be executed *every time* the loop is traversed.

Comment: I added some test code for #1 vs #2. Not sure how to test #3 vs #4.

Comment: no, in Lua the specifications for the `for` loop are only evaluated once, at the start.

Comment: And to test #3 vs #4 the only thing you can do is misure the time taken. You'll find that #4 is faster anyway.

Answer (score 2):

For the first part of the question, the [manual](http://www.lua.org/manual/4.0/manual.html#4.4) (see §4.4.4) is clear:

> A for statement like
>
> ```
>        for var = e1 ,e2, e3 do block end
> ```
>
> is equivalent to the code:
>
> ```
>        do
>          local var, _limit, _step = tonumber(e1), tonumber(e2), tonumber(e3)
>          if not (var and _limit and _step) then error() end
>          while (_step>0 and var<=_limit) or (_step<=0 and var>=_limit) do
>            block
>            var = var+_step
>          end
>        end
> ```
>
> Both the limit and the step are evaluated only once, before the loop starts.